# is this the right way to apply a single rewrite rule to multiple pages?

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to use .htaccess but i'm a bit lost at this point. I was wondering how would you do 
a rewriting for multiple pages.

```
RewriteRule ^your-order/$ /page1.php,page2.php,page3.php [L]
```

or should i just do this:

```
RewriteRule ^your-order/$ /page1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^your-order/$ /page2.php [L]
RewriteRule ^your-order/$ /page3.php [L]
```

also i was wondering if rewriterule would still execute if the page has a parameter:

```
 URL: page1.php?test=hello


RewriteRule ^your-order/$ /page1.php [L]
```

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish? I'm thinking you want to serve `your-order`  when the user requests pageN.php, in which case you have the rewrites backward.  Please tell us what the user would submit, and what page you would serve to that input./

Comment: i was thinking that when they access pageN.php the url will be rewritten to your-order. I'm sorry for the very broad question, its just that this is my first time handling htaccess. regarding my second question. is it possible?

Comment: Do you want it actually redirected in their browsers, or internally rewritten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming from your question about the query string params that you actually have the concept of the rewrites backward.  The first expression is the submitted URL (pageN.php) and the second one is where it should be redirected or rewritten (your-order). In that case, you need only one rule.

Unless you need to take special action if a query string parameter is present (like go to a different page entirely), you don't need to match the query string.  Query strings are matched in separate `RewriteCond` conditions rather than in the `RewriteRule`.

```
RewriteEngine On
# Rewrite page1, page2, page3 to your-order
# Add as many other pages as necessary separated by |
# The QSA appends any additional querystring to your-order
RewriteRule ^(page1|page2|page3)\.php your-order [L,QSA]
```

If your pages are actually named with the number at the end (which I doubt), you could use this expression instead:

```
RewriteRule ^page[0-9]+\.php your-order [L,QSA]
```

In either case, if you want the end user's browser to be redirected to the your-order URL, rather than an internal and invisible rewrite, change `[L,QSA]` to `[L,R,QSA]`

Comment: so that's what you meant by backwards. thank you. will try this out. but regarding the question with: what if the pageN.php contained a parameter will htaccess still rewrite it? even though in the rule it does not have a parameter?

Comment: @magicianIam The QSA handles that and passes the query string along.  You don't match query strings in RewriteRule, but you can match them in RewriteCond if you need to take special action.  The rule above will match regardless of query string.

Comment: so even if a parameter is present it will neglect it and still do the rewrite. thanks for that info. i will try this out.